# How is the request using wordpress site to requests config files?

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress

I was looking through my apache `error.log` and I noticed there were a few attempts made to get `wp-config.php` which failed.

Strangely it said the requested was the site itself.

How is the attacker/bot doing this?

Here is the log [Replaced actual url with example]:

```
[Sun Mar 20 09:06:40 2016] [error] [client 105.228.84.134] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function _deprecated_file() in /var/www/example/wp-includes/rss-functions.php on line 8, referer: http://example.co.za/
[Sun Mar 20 09:06:41 2016] [error] [client 105.228.84.134] File does not exist: /var/www/example/wp-content/debug.log, referer: http://example.co.za/
[Sun Mar 20 09:06:42 2016] [error] [client 105.228.84.134] File does not exist: /var/www/example/wp-config.php~, referer: http://example.co.za/
[Sun Mar 20 09:06:42 2016] [error] [client 105.228.84.134] File does not exist: /var/www/example/#wp-config.php#, referer: http://example.co.za/
[Sun Mar 20 09:06:42 2016] [error] [client 105.228.84.134] File does not exist: /var/www/example/wp-config.php.save, referer: http://example.co.za/
[Sun Mar 20 09:06:44 2016] [error] [client 105.228.84.134] File does not exist: /var/www/example/wp-config.old, referer: http://example.co.za/
[Sun Mar 20 09:06:42 2016] [error] [client 105.228.84.134] File does not exist: /var/www/example/wp-config.php.swp, referer: http://example.co.za/
[Sun Mar 20 09:06:42 2016] [error] [client 105.228.84.134] File does not exist: /var/www/example/wp-config.php.swo, referer: http://example.co.za/
[Sun Mar 20 09:06:42 2016] [error] [client 105.228.84.134] File does not exist: /var/www/example/.wp-config.php.swp, referer: http://example.co.za/
[Sun Mar 20 09:06:42 2016] [error] [client 105.228.84.134] File does not exist: /var/www/example/wp-config.bak, referer: http://example.co.za/
[Sun Mar 20 09:06:42 2016] [error] [client 105.228.84.134] File does not exist: /var/www/example/wp-config.php_bak, referer: http://example.co.za/
[Sun Mar 20 09:06:42 2016] [error] [client 105.228.84.134] File does not exist: /var/www/example/wp-config.php.bak, referer: http://example.co.za/
[Sun Mar 20 09:06:44 2016] [error] [client 105.228.84.134] File does not exist: /var/www/example/wp-config.save, referer: http://example.co.za/
[Sun Mar 20 09:06:44 2016] [error] [client 105.228.84.134] File does not exist: /var/www/example/wp-config.php.old, referer: http://example.co.za/
[Sun Mar 20 09:06:45 2016] [error] [client 105.228.84.134] File does not exist: /var/www/example/wp-config.php.orig, referer: http://example.co.za/
[Sun Mar 20 09:06:45 2016] [error] [client 105.228.84.134] File does not exist: /var/www/example/wp-config.php.original, referer: http://example.co.za/
[Sun Mar 20 09:06:45 2016] [error] [client 105.228.84.134] File does not exist: /var/www/example/wp-config.orig, referer: http://example.co.za/
[Sun Mar 20 09:06:45 2016] [error] [client 105.228.84.134] File does not exist: /var/www/example/wp-config.original, referer: http://example.co.za/
[Sun Mar 20 09:06:47 2016] [error] [client 105.228.84.134] File does not exist: /var/www/example/wp-config.txt, referer: http://example.co.za/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `referer` header is sent by the client. So much like something like the `user agent` header, it can easily be spoofed. Pretty much never trust anything the client can send.

Comment: How does it know the directory structure though?

Comment: its just looking for `/wp-config.php.swp` the webserver is adding the rest

Answer (score 1):

Apache is just reporting the [HTTP referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) that is sent in the HTTP headers. That isn't validated in any way so they can easily set the referer to any value. The only time looking at the referer (apart from statistics)  is remotely useful is when someone tries to share say an image on your site from another site that points at yours. That only works because the end-user will normally be using a browser that passes on an accurate referer.